# How can I streamline these tasks?

Tags: node.js

I'm programming with nodeJS. After I edit my code, I have to:

1. Save the code in TextMate: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>
2. Shut down the server in bash: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
3. Restart the server in bash: `node myCode.js`
4. Refresh Google Chrome: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>

Doing these steps over and over is quite repetitive. Is there a way to program my computer (mac OS X) to do all these steps in one go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about the google chrome refresh but I use the 'node-dev' package via npm (npm install -g node-dev) and then run: node-dev app.js

It watches all of your files and restarts your node process each time the files change, eliminating steps 2+3.

Here's the Github link if you prefer not to use npm: https://github.com/fgnass/node-dev

*(edit: Updated npm install command to include -g per HE's advice below)*

Comment: I get the following error

`npm WARN prefer global node-dev@0.1.8 should be installed with -g`

Comment: You should run `npm install node-dev -g`. This installs the package into the global node prefix, so that it is available anywhere on the system.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [keyboard maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) for general UI automation and scripting.  You may also want to look into the [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) npm module which will restart your node.js server whenever a file changes.  In practice, nodemon hasn't been a workable solution for me, though. It's similar to the node-dev package Brad suggested.

Comment: Why was nodemon not a workable solution for you?

Comment: None of these approaches AFAIK are intelligent about when to restart the app.  So, for example, my system tests are running and I save a file, it will restart the app under my systems tests, sometimes leaving stale data in the DB.  It's just a very blunt/dumb approach.  It can be helpful but it's not a great solution.  I've fallen back to setting up a Keyboard Maestro macro that manually kills and restarts the server when I want.